# Possible Array combinations based on constraints

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

How many unique arrays of m elements exist such that they contain numbers in the range [1,n] and there exists atleast one subsequence {1,2,3,4....n}?

Constraints: m > n

I thought of combinations approach. But there will be repetitions.
In my approach, I first lay out all the numbers from 1 to n.
For example, if m=n+1, answer is n^2. (n spots available, each number in range [1,n])
Now, I think there might be a DP relation for further calculation, but I am not being able to figure it out.

Comment: Please show us what you have done to solve the problem. SO is not a site where you can copy paste your assignment questions and get answers for them.

Comment: _@J.Doe_ I could give you a solution in [tag:malbolge] language, would that be OK?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Language is no issue. I just need an efficient algorithm. Which can run in linear/sub-linear time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [I removed language tags](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38548848/revisions) as the question didn't seem to pertain to any specific language.  (FWIW, I also voted to close)

Comment: _@J.Doe_ Face it: Your question is way too broad. Unless you can give us a reasonable approach you tried in pseudo code or whatever, you cannot ask such questions here.

Comment: @jedwards Edit for improvement, not to save questions from being (obviously) too broad (as it still is).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I seem to have hit a brick wall here. Can't think of anything other than brute force, Can you please help?

Comment: @J.Doe Given `n=3` and `m=4`, you're saying the answer is `n^2=9`, but I only see `2n=6`. Please explain.

Comment: 1,1,2,3     1,2,1,3    1,2,3,1    2,1,2,3    1,2,2,3    1,2,3,2    1,2,3,3    3,1,2,3
 1,3,2,3

Anyway, do you have an algorithm in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for n=3 and m=5. The green squares are the subsequence. The subsequence consists of the first `1` in the array, the first `2` that's after the first `1`, etc. Squares that aren't part of the subsequence can either take `n` values if they are after the end of the subsequence, or `n-1` values otherwise.

[image]

So the answer to this example is `1*9 + 3*6 + 6*4 = 51`, which is easily verified by brute force. The coefficients 1,3,6 appear to be related to [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). The rest is left to the reader.

Comment: dp[1][1]=1;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        dp[i][0]=pow(n-1,i);
    }
if(j==n) dp[i][j]=(dp[i-1][j-1]+n*dp[i-1][j])
else dp[i][j]= (dp[i-1][j-1]+(n-1)*dp[i-1][j])
Answer is dp[m][n]

I figured out till here. But this is O(mn). I need something in linear time.

Comment: @J.Doe I don't see how your comment is related to the excellent answer here. You seem stuck on the idea of dynamic programming, but this answer suggests a relatively simple calculation based on enumerating solutions.

Comment: Sorry, Figured it out. Thanks.